# Aligning forms to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align these two forms to the right as I have got a map on the left side and I dont want these forms appearing on the bottom of the page. I am not very good at css . Could someone please tell me how I could align these two forms to the right? Thanks in advance.

```
<h2> Save Animal's Location </h2>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="firstname">
latitude: <input type ="text" name="lat" >
longitude <input type ="text" name="lon">
Date: <input type="date" name="dateseen">
Time: <input type="time" name="timeseen">


<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<h2> Search </h2>
<form action = "search.php" method = "post" >
  Search for: <input type = "text" name ="find" /> in
  <select NAME = "field">
    <Option VALUE = "Animal Type"> Animal Type</option>
    <Option VALUE = "latitude"> Latitude</option>
    <Option VALUE = "longitude"> longitude</option>
    <Option VALUE = "dateseen"> Date Required</option>
    <Option VALUE = "timeseen"> Time</option>
  </Select>
  <input type= "hidden" name = "searching" value ="yes"/>
  <input type= "submit" name = "search" value ="Search"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/e92A5/1/

In the CSS, play with the width values to get the result you need. You can use %values as I have below, or you can use pixel values , e.g. 480px

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Please see updated solution using your map info:

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/e92A5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
map here
</div>

<div class= "right">

    <h2> Save Animal's Location </h2>
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="firstname">
latitude: <input type ="text" name="lat" >
longitude <input type ="text" name="lon">
Date: <input type="date" name="dateseen">
Time: <input type="time" name="timeseen">


<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>



<h2> Search </h2>
<form action = "search.php" method = "post" >
Search for: <input type = "text" name ="find" /> in
<select NAME = "field">
<Option VALUE = "Animal Type"> Animal Type</option>
<Option VALUE = "latitude"> Latitude</option>
<Option VALUE = "longitude"> longitude</option>
<Option VALUE = "dateseen"> Date Required</option>
<Option VALUE = "timeseen"> Time</option>
</Select>
<input type= "hidden" name = "searching" value ="yes"/>
<input type= "submit" name = "search" value ="Search"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
float:left;
width:50%; 
background-color:pink;
}
.right{
float:right;
width:50%;
background-color:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did work however my map is created in a way that only when I click on a button the map appears. When the map appears the two forms go to the bottom of the right side? Any way I can prevent this?

Comment: @user3293736 can you post a url to demonstrate?

Comment: This is close: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/e92A5/ -- you will probably need to refine the widths of the the map and form divs some more, depending on the specifics of your page

Comment: Thanks that worked mostly except the 'get location ' button keeps moving now. Thanks